# Monodroid Deleteing GetExternalFilesDir On Every Debug Session (Unwanted Behavior)

Tags: xamarin.android

I recently upgraded my project to Mono For Android v4.2.  With this update, when ever I deploy my app to my device, all files I've previously created in the directory returned by **GetExternalFilesDir("db")** are deleted.  I don't want this behavior.  The previous version of M4A I was using did not do this unwanted behavior.

Should I be using a different Method to get a directory to store my files in?  I have seen getExternalStorageDirectory() suggested but I don't even see that method available in Mono For Android.

I want this behavior: I want these files to be deleted when the user truly unisntalls my app, but I don't want them deleted if it's just installing an update.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Mono for Android -> Preserve something something something